# Application Layer Protocols

Tags: osi

I'd like to know, What the Application Layer Protocols have in common? client-server model could be one?

How to know if the protocol belongs to application layer just observing their features?

Comment: [Application Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) describes the general properties...

Comment: I read, but unfortunately I can't identify them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a single rule to identify an Application Layer Protocol. If you compare the *OSI model* and the *Internet Protocol Suite* the single common feature is that it **controls the communication among processes**.

In the *Internet Protocol Suite*  the Application Layer is on top of TCP / UDP. It includes protocols as:

- Routing protocols (peer to peer) (RIP, OSPF, BGP, etc.)
- Data downloading protocols (server -> client) (FTP, HTTP, TFTP)
- Human interaction protocols (peer to peer & server -> client)  (XMPP, H323, SIP, RTP)

Comment: While BGP and RIP work as examples, neither OSPF or EIGRP do. OSPF and EIGRP do not utilize TCP/UDP, rather they provide their own L4 protocol and as such do not fit as examples in your list.